# How to Insert ListActivity in Fragment of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, listactivity

I am working on Navigaion Drawer and I do have ListActivity and Fragment Activity . And i want to see the ListActivity in Fragment. But it is giving me error while inserting code of ListActivity in Fragment.
I have gone through web but really not got any effective result.

**Here Fragment Activity**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    public boolean net;
    ImageView ivIcon;
    TextView tvItemName;

    public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
    public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";

    public FragmentOne() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container,
                false);

        ivIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag1_icon);
        tvItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag1_text);

        tvItemName.setText(getArguments().getString(ITEM_NAME));
        ivIcon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(
                getArguments().getInt(IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID)));
        return view;

    }

}
```

ListActivity

```
public class MainTwitter extends ListActivity {

    private ListActivity activity;

    final static String LOG_TAG = "rnc";
     ListView listview;

     TextView text;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.twit_list);

         activity = this;

        downloadTweets();


          listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int position, long id) {   
                 // selected item
                 String lst_txt = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();

                 System.out.println("Display text"+lst_txt ); 
                 // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                 Intent i = **new Intent(FragmentOne.this, SingleListItem.class);**
                 // sending data to new activity
                 i.putExtra("product",lst_txt );
                 startActivity(i);
               }
            });
    }

    // download twitter timeline after first checking to see if there is a network connection
    public void downloadTweets() {
        TwitterUser o = new TwitterUser();
        String m = o.getValue();

         System.out.println("Kida   "+m);
          listview = this.**getListView();**
          String ScreenName =m;

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) **getSystemService**(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadTwitterTask().execute(ScreenName);
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "No network connection available.");
        }
    }

    // Uses an AsyncTask to download a Twitter user's timeline
    private class DownloadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "keyXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "sXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        final static String TwitterTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
        final static String TwitterStreamURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";


        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
        @Override
        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        //this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Boys.this, ""," Look whose back !! Ok Let me see what i have for you ");  
            try{
            progressDialog = **new ProgressDialog(FragmentOne.this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);**
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loader_2));
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ! Unwrapping Something for You...");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(**getApplicationContext()**,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... screenNames) {
            String result = null;

            if (screenNames.length > 0) {
                result = getTwitterStream(screenNames[0]);
            }
            return result;
        }

        // onPostExecute convert the JSON results into a Twitter object (which is an Array list of tweets
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Twitter twits = jsonToTwitter(result);

            // lets write the results to the console as well
            for (Tweet tweet : twits) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, tweet.getText());
            }

          /// ArrayAdapter<Tweet> al = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>();
            //  listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,al.toArray(new String[al.size()])));

            System.out.println("Kamina "+ twits);

            // send the tweets to the adapter for rendering
        //  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, twits);
        //  setListAdapter(adapter);


                ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>**(getBaseContext()**,R.layout.customgrid,R.id.texts, twits);
                **setListAdapter**(adapter);



    //      ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this,twits); 

         //   setListAdapter(myAdapter);

        //    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.customgrid,arr);
         //   lst.setAdapter(ad);

            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        // converts a string of JSON data into a Twitter object
        private Twitter jsonToTwitter(String result) {
            Twitter twits = null;
            if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    twits = gson.fromJson(result, Twitter.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // just eat the exception
                }
            }
            return twits;
        }

        // convert a JSON authentication object into an Authenticated object
        private Authenticated jsonToAuthenticated(String rawAuthorization) {
            Authenticated auth = null;
            if (rawAuthorization != null && rawAuthorization.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    auth = gson.fromJson(rawAuthorization, Authenticated.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // just eat the exception
                }
            }
            return auth;
        }

        private String getResponseBody(HttpRequestBase request) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

                if (statusCode == 200) {

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    sb.append(reason);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
            } catch (IOException ex2) {
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String getTwitterStream(String screenName) {
            String results = null;

            // Step 1: Encode consumer key and secret
            try {
                // URL encode the consumer key and secret
                String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
                String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");

                // Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character, and the
                // encoded consumer secret
                String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;

                // Base64 encode the string
                String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(combined.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                // Step 2: Obtain a bearer token
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TwitterTokenURL);
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encoded);
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
                String rawAuthorization = getResponseBody(httpPost);
                Authenticated auth = jsonToAuthenticated(rawAuthorization);

                // Applications should verify that the value associated with the
                // token_type key of the returned object is bearer
                if (auth != null && auth.token_type.equals("bearer")) {

                    // Step 3: Authenticate API requests with bearer token
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL + screenName+"&count=10");

                    // construct a normal HTTPS request and include an Authorization
                    // header with the value of Bearer <>
                    httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.access_token);
                    httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    // update the results with the body of the response
                    results = getResponseBody(httpGet);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex1) {
            }
            return results;
        }
    }






}
```

Updated Fragment by inserting ListActivity Giving me errors marked as bold

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    public boolean net;
    ImageView ivIcon;
    TextView tvItemName;

    public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
    public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";
    final static String LOG_TAG = "rnc";
     ListView listview;

    public FragmentOne() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twit_list, container,
                false);


        downloadTweets();


          listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int position, long id) {   
                 // selected item
                 String lst_txt = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();

                 System.out.println("Display text"+lst_txt ); 
                 // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                 Intent i = new Intent(MainTwitter.this, SingleListItem.class);
                 // sending data to new activity
                 i.putExtra("product",lst_txt );
                 startActivity(i);
               }
            });







        return view;

    }


    public void downloadTweets() {
        TwitterUser o = new TwitterUser();
        String m = o.getValue();

         System.out.println("Kida   "+m);
          listview = this.getListView();
          String ScreenName =m;

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadTwitterTask().execute(ScreenName);
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "No network connection available.");
        }
    }



    // Uses an AsyncTask to download a Twitter user's timeline
        private class DownloadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "wfbgrsbsrtbvrts4326243bDkqU";
            final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "grerrereonbtrsbtrsb454325624364236";
            final static String TwitterTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
            final static String TwitterStreamURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";


            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
            @Override
            // can use UI thread here
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            //this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Boys.this, ""," Look whose back !! Ok Let me see what i have for you ");  
                try{
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainTwitter.this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loader_2));
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ! Unwrapping Something for You...");
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... screenNames) {
                String result = null;

                if (screenNames.length > 0) {
                    result = getTwitterStream(screenNames[0]);
                }
                return result;
            }

            // onPostExecute convert the JSON results into a Twitter object (which is an Array list of tweets
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Twitter twits = jsonToTwitter(result);

                // lets write the results to the console as well
                for (Tweet tweet : twits) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, tweet.getText());
                }

              /// ArrayAdapter<Tweet> al = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>();
                //  listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(MainActivity.this,al.toArray(new String[al.size()])));

                System.out.println("Kamina "+ twits);

                // send the tweets to the adapter for rendering
            //  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, twits);
            //  setListAdapter(adapter);


                    ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(getBaseContext(),R.layout.customgrid,R.id.texts, twits);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);



        //      ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this,twits); 

             //   setListAdapter(myAdapter);

            //    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.customgrid,arr);
             //   lst.setAdapter(ad);

                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            // converts a string of JSON data into a Twitter object
            private Twitter jsonToTwitter(String result) {
                Twitter twits = null;
                if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        twits = gson.fromJson(result, Twitter.class);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                        // just eat the exception
                    }
                }
                return twits;
            }

            // convert a JSON authentication object into an Authenticated object
            private Authenticated jsonToAuthenticated(String rawAuthorization) {
                Authenticated auth = null;
                if (rawAuthorization != null && rawAuthorization.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        auth = gson.fromJson(rawAuthorization, Authenticated.class);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                        // just eat the exception
                    }
                }
                return auth;
            }

            private String getResponseBody(HttpRequestBase request) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

                    if (statusCode == 200) {

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

                        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                    } else {
                        sb.append(reason);
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
                } catch (IOException ex2) {
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }

            private String getTwitterStream(String screenName) {
                String results = null;

                // Step 1: Encode consumer key and secret
                try {
                    // URL encode the consumer key and secret
                    String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
                    String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");

                    // Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character, and the
                    // encoded consumer secret
                    String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;

                    // Base64 encode the string
                    String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(combined.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                    // Step 2: Obtain a bearer token
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TwitterTokenURL);
                    httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encoded);
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
                    String rawAuthorization = getResponseBody(httpPost);
                    Authenticated auth = jsonToAuthenticated(rawAuthorization);

                    // Applications should verify that the value associated with the
                    // token_type key of the returned object is bearer
                    if (auth != null && auth.token_type.equals("bearer")) {

                        // Step 3: Authenticate API requests with bearer token
                        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL + screenName+"&count=10");

                        // construct a normal HTTPS request and include an Authorization
                        // header with the value of Bearer <>
                        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.access_token);
                        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        // update the results with the body of the response
                        results = getResponseBody(httpGet);
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex1) {
                }
                return results;
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Rohit5k2
actually when i insert the code of listactivity in Fragment it shows many red line keywords in eclipse and directly calling listactivity makes null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

You can access the activity the fragment is attached to by calling `getActivity()` in the Fragment source code.

The `getActivity()` call from a fragment may return null when activity is destroyed or you call it when the fragment is not attached to activity yet. Just check for NULL when using it.
You may save the activity from this fragment's method:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Comment: you want me to write this code in Fragment Activity. Or i am not getting your point.
`@Override
 public void onAttach(ListActivity activity) {
     super.onAttach(activity);
 }`

Comment: First thing, `getActivity()` method can be called in any class extends `Fragment`. You can use this method and cast to your desired activity type. Secondary, the `@Override public void onAttach(ListActivity activity) { super.onAttach(activity); }` is the super method that in `Fragment` class, you can override it to interact with the activity when your fragment is attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your  **ListView** in not in the **fragment**, its on the Activity, make sure that your R.layout.fragment_layout_one layout has the **listview** then you can do something like this on your `**FragmentOne`;

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container,
                    false);

            //prepare the ListView
            listview = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

            //a collection to fill the listview adapter.
            String items  = new String[]{"item1", "item2"}

            ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);


            //set an adapter
            listview.setAdapter(itemsAdapter );


            //other views...
            return view;

        }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have copied whole code ListActivity to Fragment , but it shows too many red line eclipse error and fail to rectify all error .
Can u edit the above code and show me right code please

Comment: i will make twit_list.xml that have listview , the same xml used for listactivity.
I want when i choose option from navigation drawer the listview activity open instead of Fragment one.

Comment: i have updated the Fragment  class , but gives me error can you check it